# countering a div opacity?

Tags: css

If I have a div that acts like a box, and I make it real sexy with 10% opacity. How do I counter it since everything in the div also gets the opacity. Lets say i have a box(div) with a 1px border and text, putting opacity on it will make it look bad and i only want opacity on the background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a semi-transparent PNG image for the element's background. You'll need a fix such as [Supersleight](http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6) for IE6 support.

Comment: because of all the browser types i think a PNG is the best choice if i were not to use a lib like jquery or something (if it has the function i need). thanks all for all answeres!

Answer (score 12):

This is how you can apply opacity on background colors only, and not to the whole element and his children:

```
background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5) //gives you a black background with 50% opacity
```

you can test it out here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ypaTH/

there was a similar question here:
[How to give cross browser transparency to element's background only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757605/how-to-give-cross-browser-transparency-to-elements-background-only/2757677#2757677) (with IE version)

Comment: This (while being the 'correct' solution and a CSS3-feature) only works in modern browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Safari.

Comment: you can find the IE version in the other answer i gave on the previous toppic.

Comment: and opacity does not work in IE to so i though he wouldn't care

Answer (score 6):

The contents of an element that have opacity inherit that opacity. You'll need to break it into two pieces: the background and the contents. Absolutely position the contents on top of the background. Your contents cannot be within the opacity element.

Comment: This is true if you're talking about `opacity` the CSS property, but there are several other ways of achieving the effect.