# Problems with transparency in CSS

Tags: html, css

Ok so heres the deal. I have a page I'm creating in html and css. I've got a div whose background needs to be transparent. 
However when I use `opacity: .6`; Everything in the div goes see through.

Is there any way to fix this so it works in safari, IE, and firefox?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to give cross browser transparency to element's background only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757605/how-to-give-cross-browser-transparency-to-elements-background-only)

Answer (score 7):

No, there's no real way to fix this problem (though you can in CSS3). There are two possible approaches:

1) Use a transparent png background rather than doing it with CSS (with hacks for IE6 which doesn't allow transparent pngs)

2) Use two separate divs, and use absolute positioning to position one over the top of the other. This requires knowing certain dimensions, so may not always apply, but may work in your situation.

Comment: I don't understand why this is being downvoted, it was the first answer posted that even indicated basic comprehension of the problem presented by the question. I've upvoted to compensate.

Answer (score 2):

```
.outer {
    position: relative
}
.background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000; /* Or whatever */
    opacity: 0.6;
    -moz-opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
}

<div class="outer">
    <div class="background"></div>
    Content
</div>
```

Note that sometimes the `height: 100%` rule for `.background` doesn't work in IE 6, in which case you should try applying `hasLayout` to first `.outer`, and if that fails to `.background` as well (you can add `hasLayout` with the CSS rule `zoom: 1` without side-effect). If neither of those works, you'll likely need an `expression` value for IE 6. If you need further help leave a comment.

As smerriman [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274449/problems-with-transparency-in-css/3274474#3274474), it's much simpler in browsers which support CSS3 (more specifically, `rgba` or `hsla` color values). It would be as simple as `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use transparent image as a background for that element. When you use opacity in css for a given element, everything in that element and including that element receives that styling. Look here:

http://jsfiddle.net/zV4BR/

Answer (score 0):

you should use both

opacity in css and

filter:alpha(opacity=60);

for ie and stuff

Answer (score 0):

use this method

[How to give cross browser transparency to element's background only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757605/how-to-give-cross-browser-transparency-to-elements-background-only/2757677#2757677)

use Rgba instead opacity. see example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ypaTH/

you will have to set background on inner elements also.

**Edit:** to make rgab code for IE use this http://kimili.com/journal/rgba-hsla-css-generator-for-internet-explorer/

Comment: Questioner wants cross-browser solution. `rgba` is not supported across all widely used browsers.

Comment: Okay fair enough, but it's worth noting that `filter` rules can cause side-effects that are undesirable (in some circumstances links are not clickable, for instance), and that as a single CSS rule they must be joined with commas if there is more than one. It may be a solution to the questioner's problem, but it does have its caveats.

Answer (score -1):

it should be

> opacity:0.6

beside that opacity works differently depending which web browser you use